# What are the spirit-generating mechanics for Crippling Wave - Rising Tide?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

In the skill description for **[Crippling Wave](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/crippling-wave) - Rising Tide**, it is stated that

> Critical Hits generate an additional 5 Spirit.

Since Crippling Wave typically hits multiple enemies with each use, is the 5 additional spirit generated for a critical hit per enemy, or per use of Crippling Wave?

(the same question applies for **[Fists of Thunder](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/fists-of-thunder) - Quickening** and **[Deadly Reach](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/deadly-reach) - Strike from Beyond**, but I'm mainly interested in the rune with Crippling Wave, since it tends to hit many more enemies)

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67514/which-monk-spirit-generator-skills-generates-spirit-the-fastest this question strongly implies that you will be able to crit multiple enemies at once with crippling wave. I have been unable to find any hard source that describes this effect however.

Comment: Thanks, that link does seem to imply so! Unfortunately I haven't noticed any huge jump in spirit when I've been using Rising Tide thus far. Perhaps my crit chance is too low.

Comment: I would suspect that it works like this, the equivalent effects for Wizards do stack with multiple hits (Prodigy + Signature abilities) although that has not critical hit dependency. Saying that though, due to the RNG of critting, I would suggest that this would work => Hitting five enemies and critting three times = 15 spirit. I will test it at some point in the future and revisit this, my monk isn't quite ready for testing this.

Answer (score 1):

I did a test in 1.03 and the Spirit generation is per crit hit per enemy, so if one Crippling Wave hit 5 enemies out of which 2 were crit hits, 10 additional Spirit was generated.